# How to dump data in table from CSV file using talend by manually increment in id as Max(id)+1 for each row in csv

Tags: database, etl, talend, csvtotable

I am trying to perform ETL Talend Job where I have records in csv file and have to Dump those records in table. My table has Primary key column i.e Id. CSV file does not have Id column. So I have to get max(Id)+1 from table and insert the csv rows one by one with incremental id for each row.

Tried Setting Max(Id) into global variable and increment this id as id+1 in Tmap for each row.
But It does not get increment for each record in Csv file

Comment: Can you append your code for better understanding of your situation?

Comment: No It is no possible to add code here. It is just that the table in which I am trying to insert from that table I have to get max id increment by one and insert that id along with other columns in csv file for each row in csv

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sequence in your database. Create a view of your sequence and import as a lookup table in Talend. Using TMap, pass the column to your ID. Let me know if you face any issues or further details.

[image]

Note:
Make sure you make Reload at each row in Lookup Model so that new id gets generated for each row.

Thank you